# Rearrange specific rows in descending order

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like this:

```
          names diam_1 diam_2 diam_3
1      Adam     17      5      4
2      Bert     NA      7      4
3 Charlotte      5      9      9
4    Daniel      6      3      6
5  Eleonore      9     NA      4
6     Frank      6      6     NA
```

How can I rearrange the values `(diam_1 - diam_3)` for each person in descending order, so that I get the following desired output?

```
      names diam_1 diam_2 diam_3
1      Adam     17      5      4
2      Bert      7      4     NA
3 Charlotte      9      9      5
4    Daniel      6      6      3
5  Eleonore      9      4     NA
6     Frank      6      6     NA
```

**Data**

```
structure(list(names = c("Adam", "Bert", "Charlotte", "Daniel", 
"Eleonore", "Frank"), diam_1 = c(17, NA, 5, 6, 9, 6), diam_2 = c(5, 
7, 9, 3, NA, 6), diam_3 = c(4, 4, 9, 6, 4, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restructure the table to long format then sort the values and revise the diam name then pivot it wide again.

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(cols = diam_1:diam_3, names_to = "diam", values_to = "value") |>
  group_by(names) |>
  arrange(desc(value)) |>
  mutate(diam = paste0("diam_", row_number())) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = diam, values_from = value)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#> # Groups:   names [6]
#>   names     diam_1 diam_2 diam_3
#>   <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 Adam          17      5      4
#> 2 Charlotte      9      9      5
#> 3 Eleonore       9      4     NA
#> 4 Bert           7      4     NA
#> 5 Daniel         6      6      3
#> 6 Frank          6      6     NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Using `apply` and `sort` you could do:

```r
dat[2:4] <- t(apply(dat[2:4], 1, sort, na.last = TRUE, decreasing = TRUE))

dat
#>       names diam_1 diam_2 diam_3
#> 1      Adam     17      5      4
#> 2      Bert      7      4     NA
#> 3 Charlotte      9      9      5
#> 4    Daniel      6      6      3
#> 5  Eleonore      9      4     NA
#> 6     Frank      6      6     NA
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this with dplyr

If you need to visualice the substraction use a mock row with it and then order it

```
df_ordered <- df %>% mutate(mock=diam_1-diam_3) %>% arrange(desc(mock)) %>% select(-mock)
```

Otherwise use the function arrange and substract inside

```
df_ordered2 <- df %>% arrange(desc(diam_1-diam_3))
```